# Rerun Main method from Main Method

Tags: java, netbeans

Basically the last thing I need to do for this Math Quiz I have to program, I have to ask the user if they would like to answer more problems, if yes, rerun everything in the Main Method. If no, print goodbye. The no is easy, but I'm unsure how to tell it to rerun the main method if they say yes. Here is the code in my main method.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int digit = 0;

    String result1 = getUserChoice("");

    digit = getNumberofDigit1(digit);

    int numberOfProblems = amountOfProblems();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfProblems; i++) {
    int number1 = getRandomNumber1(digit);
    int number2 = getRandomNumber2(digit);

    System.out.println("Enter your answer to the following problem: \n" + 
            number1 + result1 + number2);
    int correctAnswer = getCorrectAnswer(number1, result1, number2);

    int userAnswer = getUserAnswer();

    CheckandDisplayResult(correctAnswer, userAnswer);
    }
        System.out.println("Would you like to solve more probelms(Y/N)? ");
        String moreProblems = in.next();

        if ("Y".equals(moreProblems)){
            digit = 0;

    result1 = getUserChoice("");

    digit = getNumberofDigit1(digit);

    numberOfProblems = amountOfProblems();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfProblems; i++) {
    int number1 = getRandomNumber1(digit);
    int number2 = getRandomNumber2(digit);

    System.out.println("Enter your answer to the following problem: \n" + 
            number1 + result1 + number2);
    int correctAnswer = getCorrectAnswer(number1, result1, number2);

    int userAnswer = getUserAnswer();

    CheckandDisplayResult(correctAnswer, userAnswer);
    }
        System.out.println("Would you like to solve more probelms(Y/N)? ");
        moreProblems = in.next();

          if ("Y".equals(moreProblems)){

        }
        System.out.println("Thank you for taking this quiz, Goodbye!");

}
```

Now I have tried something like,

if "Y".equals(moreProblems)){
copy and past the main method
}

But that has the error of requiring an infinite loops as you'd have to have the more problems statement in every if of yes, meaning it would never end coding wise, you would keep copying and pasting forever.

Answer (score 3):

You could enclose all the code you want to "re-run" in a while loop:

```
boolean run = true;
while (run) {
    // Here your code
    // Here input if user want to re-run
    if (getUserChoice("").equals("NO"))
        run = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to what others have suggested, this is the method I prefer:

```
while(true) {
    //do all your stuff
    if(/*some exit condition*/) { break; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is move everything in `main()` into another static method, call it `interact()`. Then in `main()`, just have logic which calls `interact()` as long as the user wants to interact with your program. In other words, put the math quiz into one method, and the business of presenting the quiz into `main()`. Your program will be easier to read and easier to modify further, if needed.

Comment: I thought about that, however the assignment states that all methods must be called from the main method so the quiz must stay in the main method part.

Comment: Well, then go with the while loop, as suggested by others.

Answer (score 1):

Put all of it in a big do-while loop:

```
boolean more = false;

do {

    // all your code

    more = "Y".equals(moreProblems);

} while (more);
```

Or provided your Scanner is declared outside the loop you can just:

```
do {

    // all your code

} while ("Y".equals(in.next()));
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this prototype might help you

```
import java.util.Scanner;
 public class MathsClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MathsClass object = new MathsClass();

        while(object.response())
            object.mathsQuiz();

    }

    public void mathsQuiz(){
        //your quiz functionalities
        System.out.println("Add two nos");
    }

    public boolean response(){
        System.out.println("Would u like to solve more problems? ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean response = scanner.nextBoolean();

        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can some one tell me why I have received a down vote?